# android - nexus 7 doesn't support attachment

Tags: android

I sent the apk file to Nexus 7(Jelly Bean). I try to install it, then I got the alert saying `"There is no installed app that can open this attachment. try downloading an appropriate app from android market."` Why do I get this message and what can I do to make it work?

Manifest file:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chessstopwatch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


< supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
    < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
    < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/csw_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".ChessStopWatchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ChessMoveScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                    </activity>
         <activity android:name=".CSW_Constants">
         </activity>

    </application>

< /manifest>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with either your app or with the Nexus 7. It's the Mail app in Jelly Bean. The same thing happens on the Motorola Xoom with 4.1. As Matt suggested, the Gmail app does know how to handle an .apk.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is an answer as such, but you may well find that it's not your APK that is causing the issue - my N7 refuses to open anything sent via email to my **Exchange** email account.

Try sending it to your Gmail account instead - this always works for me.